# react native: Set default payment method for stripe element component

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

[image]I am using this link to implement stripe payment:
[accept payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native)

All is working well but I am not able to make the stripe pay element check default payment method already saved for user (setting it in paymentintent creation).

In the picture below is my payment élément rendering. In it all my saved cards are présent but my default payment method is the one with 4444 not the other.

Does anyone know how to do it and show the default payment when paying

Answer (score 0):

You should create a customer Customer Ephemeral Key and pass the `customerEphemeralKeySecret` to `initPaymentSheet()` . This allows the SDK to retrieve the saved payment methods from Stripe and display them in the PaymentSheet,

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already did that and the paiement element display all saved payment methods of the user but the checked card is not thé default one

Comment: I added à screenshot to explain my use case

Comment: I'm afraid that there' no option to mark a default payment method in PaymentSheet.